# Writing a disk image back to disk with bad blocks

Tags: linux, hard-drive, backup

I'm experimenting with backing up hard drives by creating disk images rather than copying files.

If I have an image created with something like

```
dd if=/dev/sdb of=/backup/sdb.img
```

what will happen if I write this image back to the same disk with

```
dd if=/backup/sdb.img of=/dev/sdb
```

and the disk has since creating the image acquired some damaged blocks? Will the disk still work or will there be damaged files, failure to boot, etc? Could it be written back to a new hard drive of equal size in the case of a complete and utter hard drive failure?

My understanding of the internal workings of hard drives is lacking a bit to figure this out on my own and it's pretty hard to test out.

Comment: How did you back it up? Is this a disk image you intend to boot?

Comment: @FighterHayabusa - You should assume any data placed on those damaged blocks are not secure and the likelyhood of data corruption on those blocks is high. In theory if the recover software you use is set to ignore errors you can recover the image to the hdd in question.  There are ways to get the hdd to mark those blocks as bad and not use them, but it might just be easiser to replace the hdd.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Yes, some of the images I intend to boot. The images are created using dd, writing to an external HDD.

Comment: ahh, I was thinking of suggesting you mount the drives and do a file level copy otherwise. Nonetheless, I wouldn't trust the drive for long term, reliable use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DD does a perfect bit-wise copy of whatever's on the image to the drive. However, modern disks are clever enough to abstract away any bad blocks and organise things for you. If you're aware there's bad blocks, you should be aware that your disk can die at any time (but you have a backup, yay! - do NOT consider this anything other than a short term solution). Doing a format with badblocks (a windows full format or mkfs of some flavour with a -c tag) should get the disk to mark bad blocks as, well bad, and you ought to be able to take advantage of the disks internal flagging methods.

To be sure, you can probably run smartmontools (i use the graphical front end for it - gsmartcontrol), and check pending sector reallocation counts before and after your imaging.

Answer (score 2):

If disk start to have errors and those errors are not UNC (soft-bad errors) but hard-bad errors then your second *dd* command will fail with such error:

```
dd: writing to '/dev/hdc': Input/output error
499969+0 records in
499968+0 records out
```

You could try to add conv=errors - may be it will succeed.

If that was UNC errors - then it will succeed and disk will be fully usable.

Image could be written to another disk of same or bigger capacity.

Same time if you question is not about `dd` but rather regarding recovery from HDD problem I would recommend to look for [ddrescue](http://www.gnu.org/s/ddrescue/) or [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/)